# Is there a way to programmatically add stub ID's to Spring Cloud Contract Stub Runner?

Tags: java, spring, stubbing, spring-cloud-contract

I would like to stub contracts based on an ID in the url (this is for a Spring Application). Is there a way to add an ID to the Stub Runner during runtime or do all stubs have to be specifically defined in the @AutoConfigureStubRunner annotation?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can start your own BatchStubRunner and manually feed it with data. So in other words you can manually do what @AutoConfigureStubRunner does for you